# Term for women's studies person

Tags: phrase-requests, nouns

What phrase or term may be used in semi-formal writing (e.g. a news article or opinion essay) to refer to someone whose area of study or research is women's studies?  I considered "women's studies person", "women's student", and "women studier" but, while amusing, none of these seem adequate.

Example usage:

> *Women's studies person* Jane Doe coined the term "mansplaining", arguing that explaining something while being a man is inherently sexist.

Comment: "Expert"?  "Researcher"? To make this easier, imagine you were talking about "zoology" instead of "women's studies".

Comment: That would be *zoologist.* The problem with finding a Greek-derived word here is that *gynaecologist* is already taken. I guess I'm guilty of mansplaining that.

Comment: *Women's studies scholar*?

Answer (score 1):

Woman's Studies Mistress

mistress
"the woman or girl whom an animal is accustomed to obey" (OED) ,  the animal here obviously being any mansplainer.

Or a more staid definition (again from the OED)

"A female teacher; a woman qualified to teach, or particularly accomplished in some subject, skill, etc" 
Sub-definition:
"A female tutor or teacher, esp. in a school; a woman who teaches a particular subject."

> Women's studies mistress Jane Doe coined the term "mansplaining", arguing that explaining something while being a man is inherently sexist.

Comment: Yet not every student of women's studies is necessarily a woman or would otherwise be accurately addressed or described as _mistress_...

Comment: Heh. I was led astray by the OP using **Jane Doe**.

Comment: *Mistress* is basically an archaic term for a female *teacher*.  It is a somewhat less archaic term for a woman who a married man is cheating with.  I do not think you'd want to use it do describe a feminist scholar.